# Как правильно использовать GSON чтобы не получать null

Tags: android

Дело в том что иногда веб разработчики коряво пишут json в итоге получается что для 1 элемента есть допустим параметр "data", а для 2 нету в итоге при использовании GSON вылетает приложение. Есть ли способ пропустить если gson не может получить данные?

Тут ругается Android Studio пишет Cannot resolve symbol 'PhotosUrls'

```
@SerializedName("photosUrls")
    public List<PhotosUrls> photosUrls;
```

Это Json

```
    "photosUrls":[
"https://buzzar.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1.0/public/images/1481001023663-78155.jpg"
]
```

Comment: Таки, вроде, не должно вылетать... Попробуйте что-то в этом роде: `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();`

Comment: пробовал не работает. В Gson 3 элемента в списке работают и на 4 вылетает.

В Json все норм.

Comment: “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1”

вот ошибка

Comment: Ну... Покажите данные и модель для них и как парсите

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил текст

Comment: Вы пытаетесь распарсить массив из некоторых объектов, тогда как у вас массив строк

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как написать это? public String[] PhotosUrls photosUrls;

Вот так?

Comment: Нет... Просто `List<String> photosUrls`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ответ ввыглядит так
    List photosUrls